# Get flag if user property is private in Sharepoint CSOM / REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-clientobject, csom, sharepoint-online

I am using SharePoint 2013 Online in Office 365.
Currently I am getting all properties of a list of users

```
for (var i = 0; i < targetUsers.length; i++) {

     //Create new instance of UserProfilePropertiesForUser
     userProfiles[i] = peopleManager.getPropertiesFor(targetUsers[i]);
     clientContext.load(userProfiles[i]);
}
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
```

I wasn't able to get the Information if a property is flagged as "private" or "everyone. 
Is that possible to do that with REST / CSOM-API?

thx in advance